# Difference between backtick and single quote for marks

Tags: mark, jumplist, jump

[Section 3.10](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_03.html#03.10) told me that:

> The command "'mark" (single quotation mark, or apostrophe) moves you to the
> beginning of the line containing the mark.  This differs from the "`mark"
> command, which also moves you to the marked column.

But when I `:help '` or `` :help ` ``  I am given the exact same help, which is:

```
                    *'* *'a* *`* *`a*
'{a-z}  `{a-z}      Jump to the mark {a-z} in the current buffer.
```

So according to the help file there is no difference, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first paragraph that gives you the correct understanding.

The start of the Mark section (few lines before the lines you quote) is:

```
Jumping to a mark can be done in two ways:
1. With ` (backtick):
   The cursor is positioned at the specified location
   and the motion is exclusive.
2. With ' (single quote):
   The cursor is positioned on the first non-blank
   character in the line of the specified location and
   the motion is linewise.
```

Unfortunately, you also need to read the context to have the right understanding of the doc.